# How to display tiles from a GeoWebCache cache directory in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geowebcache

I'm trying to publish the cached data in geoserver with a leaflet. However, the data does not appear when publishing the cached data.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.42, 53.50], 6);

    var wmts = L.tileLayer('C:/Program Files(x86)/GeoServer 2.15.1/data_dir/gwc/web/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        wmts: true,
    });
    wmts.addTo(map);
```

the data I have cached (I got the images until the 10th zoom):

[image]

where could i have made a mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

The file names of the cached tiles inside the GeoWebCache cache directories is **not** the usual `z/y/x` scheme. Tiles are spread along more directories (possibly in an effort to work nicer with the underlying filesystem).

The file naming algorithm has been already implemented in several places, for example in https://github.com/kcl-ddh/leaflet-geowebcache-plugin/blob/master/src/Leaflet_GWC_Layer.js :

```
/*
 Copyright (c) 2013, Neil Jakeman
 GWC Layer implements access to a pre rendered GWC tile cache.
 NB. URL to take the form:
  '{s}/path/to/cache/EPSG_900913_{z}/{dir_x}_{dir_y}/{x}_{y}.png';
 Options:
 Must declare {tms:true}

*/


L.TileLayer.GWC = L.TileLayer.extend({

    _padZeros: function(unPaddedInt,padReq) {
            padded = unPaddedInt.toString()
            while (padded.length < padReq) {
                    padded = '0'+padded;
            }
            return padded
    },

    getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
        this._adjustTilePoint(tilePoint);

        return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend({
            s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint),
            z: this._getZoomForUrl(),
            dir_x: this._padZeros(Math.floor(tilePoint.x/(Math.pow(2,Math.floor(1+(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/2))))), Math.floor(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/6)+1),
            dir_y: this._padZeros(Math.floor(tilePoint.y/(Math.pow(2,Math.floor(1+(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/2))))), Math.floor(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/6)+1),
            x: this._padZeros(tilePoint.x,2+(Math.floor(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/6)*2)),
            y: this._padZeros(tilePoint.y,2+(Math.floor(this._getZoomForUrl(tilePoint)/6)*2))

        }, this.options));
    }
})
```

As you might see, the file path is `{z}/{dir_x}_{dir_y}/{x}_{y}.png` rather than the usual `{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, and `dir_x`/`dir_y`/`x`/`y` can be deterministically calculated from the global `x`/`y`/`z` tile coordinate.